# Where drush make downloading my projects?

Tags: drush

I have created a drush make file through drushmake.me

Which is, I've created a file `my.make` in `public_html` folder and run the following command:

```
drush make my.make
```

It shows all the files downloading ok, but when I am checking my `public_html` folder it's showing nothing in my `public_html`.

I don't understand where all the projects are downloaded.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally drush makes default behaviour is to create the site in the current directory - relative to where you run the command.

But the simplest way to deal with this is just to run drush-make with a parameter explicitly stating where to deploy the site:

```
drush make my.make relative/path/to/my/public_html
```

or

```
drush make my.make /absolute/path/to/my/public_html
```

Obviously replacing the path in question with the appropriate one. Don't understand UNIX file paths? Read up on them on [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Unix_style).

And while I am at it, why don't you take a look at [the drush make documentation](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/docs/make.txt) too.

There are a number of drush configuration files that affect the working directory for drush commands - the most likely candidate being a drushrc file is [example.drushrc.php](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.drushrc.php).

Comment: Thanks for your time, I am accepting your answer since it is logical, but in my case the problem was due to views slide show module, it was downloading the library and giving an error all other modules downloading status was showing ok. I removed views slideshow and the make file worked perfectly.